# Using two Google APIs with the same application

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-directory-api

I have an application which connects to Google Drive API.
Now I have to add another function which requires the Google Directory API.
I granted the necessary permissions and enabled the new API in my project.

However I'm still getting this error:

> "message" : "Access Not Configured. Admin Directory API has not been
>   used in project 594418282793 before or it is disabled. Enable it by
>   visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/admin.googleapis.com/overview?project=594418282793
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry."

The problem is that the URL in the message gives me an error; apparently the project ID is invalid.
This is the error:

> There was an error while loading
>   /apis/dashboard?project=594418282793. You are missing at least one of
>   the following required permissions:
>
> Project
>
> resourcemanager.projects.get
>
> Check that the project ID is valid and you have permissions to access
>   it.

I have no idea what is the cause of this mismatch, why the project ID provided in the error message doesn't seem to exist, and where else should I enable the second API in my application.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would doable check that you enabled it in the same project as your client credentials is from.   Or just download a new set of client credentials.

Comment: @DaImTo
Thanks! You mean the ones that are in the credentials.json , right? I have two of them, one for each API. Is that the correct way?

Comment: No, you need a single credentials json, then you can request Drive and Admin SDK scopes together or separated depending on your use case. The simple way is to request all the scopes you need so you only have to deal with one access token.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it's working with your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have miss understood how the credentials.json works.

> Access Not Configured.

Means that the credentials you have loaded for this client has not been setup for the api you are trying to connect to.

When you create a project on Google developer console this is to give google information about your application as a whole and what it is designed to do.  You should enable both apis in the single project.

Once that is done create your Oauth credentials as you did before this credential file will then be able to connect to both apis .

## googel developer console

Left hand menu click credentials then button on the top says create credentials

[image]

Once you have created it click the arrow to download you can download the file anytime

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. My problem was that whenever I enable an API I receive a set of credentials.
Here I can enable the Drive API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java
and save the credentials file.
Here I can enable the Directory API:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/java
and receive a different credentials file.

Does it matter which one I use?

Comment: Stop using that button to enable APIs do it in https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: Thank you, I enabled the two APIs there, and also created a service account which will be necessary.
Now I have an API key and an OAuth client id. I also created a credential for the service account. This had a similar format to the credentials.json but it's not accepted in the authorization flow. Is there another credential I should be getting?

Thanks again for your help. I'm completely new to Google APIs, and this setup is tricky for me now that I need two of them.

Comment: Remember a service account isnt you your going to have to grant it access to something.  The code to authenticate with a service account is not the same as the code to authcate with a web application.

Comment: Thanks again.
Here
https://console.developers.google.com/apis
I created client id and secret, but I see no way to create or obtain the credentials.json file which the application requires.

Comment: Check pictures 

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! With your help both APIs are now usable for me. Many thanks!